# how to retrieve the value of the value-tem pair in a combo box in c#.net?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this form, in which i need to populate a combo box with a text-value pair from the database, so that i can use the value in an update query to the database

i found some method that uses a class to make objects which have both text and a value as:

```
class RequestType
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public RequestType(string text, string val)
        {
            Text = text;
            Value = val;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
```

and i added them to the combo box like this

```
RequestType type1 = new RequestType("Label 1", "Value 1");
            RequestType type2 = new RequestType("Label 2", "Value 2");

            comboBox1.Items.Add(type1);
            comboBox1.Items.Add(type2);

            comboBox1.SelectedItem = type2;
```

now i don't know how to retrieve the value of the selected item, i.e. id label 1 is selected, it must return value1 and if label 2 is selected, it returns value2,

any help please??? thanxx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Items collection of a combobox is of type [ObjectCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.aspx), so when you set an item with

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(type1);
```

you are adding a RequestType object to the collection.
Now, when you want to retrieve a single selected item from that collection, you could use a syntax like this

```
RequestType t = comboBox1.SelectedItem as RequestType;
```

Theoretically, (when you have complete control on the adding of the combobox items) you could avoid to check if the conversion applied with the `as` keyword  was successful, but this is not the case because the SelectedItem could be null and therefore it is always a good practice to test with

```
   if(t != null)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(t.Value + " " + t.Text);
   }
```

Comment: Correct, but you should check if t is null... :)

Comment: Sorry @Marco, the test was coming

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use:

```
if (combobox1.SelectedItem != null)
    val2 = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as RequestType).Value;
```

or

```
string val2 = combobox1.SelectedItem != null ?
                  (comboBox1.SelectedItem as RequestType).Value :
                  null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestType type = (RequestType)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
```

Now, Value of the selected item = `type.Value`

Comment: @Marco Actually i didn't write the complete code snippet, just showed _how to get selected item value_... But any ways thats always an important thing check for...;)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the comboBox1.SelectedItem to your type, RequestType, and then you can read its properties.